# How to call iframe from another iframe and dispay it in the parent window?

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe

[image]How to call iframe (iframe A) from another iframe (iframe B) and display it in the parent window?....I could call it but it is displaying in the calling iframe not in the parent window. I am  using Asp.Net (3.5 framework) with C# .
Any help will be appreciated.
My code is as follows.....

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a shape="rect" coords="6,2,109,29" toptions="group = links, shaded = 1, type = iframe, effect = fade, width = 735, height = 400, layout = quicklook"
            href="chat.aspx" target="_parent" 
            onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
            onmouseover="MM_swapImage('01','','images/ql_02_2.jpg',1)">
            <img src="images/ql_02.jpg" name="01" width="330" height="35" border="0" id="01" />
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

As shown in the figure, I am calling an iframe 2 by click a link in another iframe 1 and display it in the main page. Now it is displayed in the iframe1 portion. I want ot display it in main page.

Answer (score 0):

it is call cross window communication , here is the demo

http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage